# Update ObservableCollection where the items are received from another List

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, observablecollection

I want to display all my CONTACTS in a ItemsControl dynamically.
I have a List Contacts in my Logic (this one gets updated if someone removed me or if someone accepted my request) and I've added this List to a ObservableCollection<> which is bound to the ListBox.

C#

```
Contacts = new ObservableCollection<Contact>(MyLogic.Current.Contacts);
```

XAML

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Contacts}" x:Name="MainPanel">
```

**And here's the problem:**
When I want to add a contact to my Contacts LIST, the ObservableCollection doesn't get updated

```
MyLogic.Current.Contacts.Add(new Contact("Fred", true));
```

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: In this case i suppose that if you exclude "ObservableCollection" from title, title will be pointless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the best solution but if you want to see where the problem is, the following code updates your UI:

```
var newContact = new Contact("Fred", true));
MyLogic.Current.Contacts.Add(newContact);
Contacts.Add(newContact);
```

A better solution is when `MyLogic.Current.Contacts` changes notify your UI via events.

**Edit:**

> The problem is that I can only update the LIST and not the
>   ObservableCollection(the list itself is in a different project)... so
>   I need a way to update the GUI when that LIST is updated

To notify UI when ever your data changes you can use events as follow:

First define an `EventArgs` which shows newly added items like this:

```
public class ModelAddedEventArgs<TModel> : EventArgs
{
    public ModelAddedEventArgs(TModel newModel)
    {
        NewModel = newModel;
    }

    public TModel NewModel { get; set; }
}
```

Then define an `EventHandler` in your `MyLogic` calss as follow:

```
public event EventHandler<ModelAddedEventArgs<Contact>> ContactAdded;

    public void AddModel(Contact model)
    {
        // first add your contact then:
        if (ActivityGroupAdded != null)
            ActivityGroupAdded(this, new ModelAddedEventArgs<Contact>(model));
    }
```

And finally use your `EventHandler` to notify UI:

```
    private void YourUIConstructor()
    {
        MyLogic += OnContactAdded;
    }
    private void OnContactAdded(object sender, ModelAddedEventArgs<Contact> e)
    {
        Contacts.Add(e.NewModel);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`ObservableCollection` is not work with source `List`. When you create it from existing `List` it only copies elements from it to inner storage.
So, you should add elements to `ObservableCollection` itself to get what you want etc.

Comment: The problem is that I can only update the LIST and not the ObservableCollection(the list itself is in a different project)... so I need a way to update the GUI when that LIST is updated

Comment: In this case you should pass your observable collection to place that update it instead of list that it updates now

Comment: If you show your code that manage LIST, i could give you advice how to do what you want.

Comment: nevermind, we've decided now to only have the ObservableCollection... thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is that you are expecting the `ObservableCollection` to be automatically updated when you add to your `List`. This is not true.

When you instantiate your `ObservableCollection`, you are taking a **copy** of your `List`, not a reference to the list itself.

Therefore, when you add a new item, you should add to your `ObservableCollection`, not your `List`. Or both. But I can't see why you would need both, I would recommend ditching your `List` altogether.

Comment: The LIST and the GUI are in 2 seperate projects and I don't want the GUI-project to manage my contacts, but only to show them